# criteriaBuilder.construct() select property of nullable child entity in DTO Projection

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

In XyzEntity user field contains both null and not null values

(Here **root.get(XyzEntity_.user) can be null**)

Code 1:

```
criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.construct(XyzStatusDTO.class, root.get(XyzEntity_.ID), 
                root.get(XyzEntity_.user).get(UserEntity_.ID),
                root.get(XyzEntity_.user).get(UserEntity_.EMAIL)
           ));
```

Code 2:

```
 criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.construct(XyzStatusDTO.class, root.get(XyzEntity_.ID), 
                root.get(XyzEntity_.user).get(UserEntity_.ID) 
           ));
```

Code 3:

```
 criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.construct(XyzStatusDTO.class, root.get(XyzEntity_.ID) 
           ));
```

Code 1 returns 12 records (only where user is not null) while Code 2 and Code 3 returns 300 results (including null user).

Any suggestions where can I put conditional statement like if user is null or not-null). So that values id user Id and email will be null if user is null, instead of skipping results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is a left join

```
      Join<XyzEntity, UserEntity> userEntityJoin = root.join("user", JoinType.LEFT);
      criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.construct(XyzStatusDTO.class, root.get(XyzEntity_.ID), 
            userEntityJoin.get(UserEntity_.ID),
            userEntityJoin.get(UserEntity_.EMAIL)
       ));
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought about it but somehow forgot to add. Can you explain how  if I fetch only pk of child entity works (code 2 works while code 1 fails)

Comment: @Tusar code 2 works because there is no implicit inner join. the implicit default inner join kicks in when you select fields of the UserEntity. that is why 1 "fails". the reason is that jpa implicit default join is inner join. with inner join you keep only records that have matching values in both tables. the solution is using left join because you always want to select the left even when there is no right value https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-types#1-implicit-inner-join-with-single-valued-association-navigation